# Как вытянуть ссылку на картинку?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, rss

Вот есть 3 разных файла:
http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=rss&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US
http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US
http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US

В них, каждый день обновляется информация (ссылка на картинку). Каким образом я могу вытянуть оттуда ссылку на картинку?

Comment: Так можно не только весь интернет перекапывать, но и взять да написать соответствующий код самому.

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в ссылке format=json сделайте и работайте как с json

пример на jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=json&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US"
})
.done(function( data ) {
   var imgUrl = data.images.image.url;
});
```

Comment: У меня что-то не работает. Можете пример кинуть?